# How to pass data from one ViewModel to another ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I have a fragment in which I have two `TextView`s with hint texts. When a user clicks on the first one a bottom sheet dialog opens and shows a list of possible options. User selects an option, and the option info is displayed in the first `TextView` instead of hint text. When the user clicks on the second `TextView` the very same bottom sheet dialog opens, but shows a filtered list of options (the list is filtered based on the first choice). User selects an option and the option info is displayed in the second `TextView` instead of the hint text as well. I have achieved to have this by using only one ViewModel for the fragment itself, but it doesn't seem right because the ViewModel does too much. Therefore, I tried using two ViewModels: one for the fragment itself to update when the options are selected, and one for the bottom sheet dialog to load the data and show them in the list. But the issue is that I cannot share the selected option from the bottom sheet dialog ViewModel to the fragment ViewModel. Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve by using two ViewModels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, as far as I know, the Google recommended approach is to have a [shared view model](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0) for such cases.

I am not sure how you implemented it in your case - but if it is something similar to what Google recommends - then it is ok.

Of course, you can create an elaborate architecture of multiple view models connected via interfaces and UI calls, but I don't know if it is worth it.

The general rule for implementing such cases is not to use the cleanest approach with a lot of abstractions and generifications but to use the most optimal one(in terms of time spent and simplicity/readability of the code) that still tries to follow OOD principles.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved with interface.I thing this is best practice.
Example: I show how send string from bottom sheet dialog to fragment.

First we create new interface

```
interface BottomSheetClickListener {
   fun onDialogClick(view: View, string: String)
}
```

Second we get in bottom sheet dialog fragment from class constructor. And we write how trigger this listener for example click textView.

```
class BottomSheetDialog(
 private val listener: BottomSheetClickListener
) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
   textView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onDialogClick(it,"String")
   }
}
```

And finally we write fragment or activity code first inheritance from our listener and create bottomSheetDialog object.

```
  class HomeFragment : Fragment(), BottomSheetClickListener {
      
     private fun openBottomSheetDialog(){
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this)
        dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "dialog")
     }

     override fun onDialogClick(string: String, id: Int) {
      //Get string from bottom sheet dialog string
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple `ViewModel`s in a `Fragment`, so there's no need to keep a huge shared `ViewModel` with all the logic of the 3 smaller ones.

You can create an extra shared `ViewModel` that only cares about the actual common data, and keep your 3 separate fragment specific `ViewModel`s separate.

```
sharedModel = activity?.run {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this)[SharedViewModel::class.java]
    } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
localViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LocalViewModel::class.java)
```